# how does this variable get set to 0?

Tags: python, variables, pygame

I have a section of code that used to work fine but has been tweaked, and now doesn't work. i found that this is because block.speed_x gets set to 0 at the start of the game loop, however i have no idea why.

```
prints = []
#imports and inits
import pygame
pygame.init()
# Global constants =============================================================
BLACK = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (   0, 255,   0)
RED   = ( 255,   0,   0)
BLUE  = (   0,   0, 255)
#Functions======================================================================
def text(text,xy):
    def draw_letter(letter,xy):
        if letter ==' ':
            l=pygame.image.load(('letters/space.png')).convert()
        elif letter == '?':
            l=pygame.image.load(('letters/QM.png')).convert()
        elif letter == '.':
            l=pygame.image.load(('letters/dot.png')).convert()
        else:
            l=pygame.image.load(('letters/'+letter+'.png')).convert()
        l.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        screen.blit(l,xy)
    def word(text,xy):
        loc=0
        for letter in text:
            draw_letter(letter,[(xy[0]+loc),xy[1]])
            loc+=15
    word(text,xy)

class shape: #basic shape
    color=255, 255, 255
    location=[0,0]
    speed_x = 0
    speed_y = 0

    def update_pos(self):
        self.location[0]+=self.speed_x
        self.location[1]+=self.speed_y

    def move(self,x,y,speed):
        if speed==0:
            self.location=[x,y]
        else:
            speed_x = speed
            speed_y = speed
            distance_y = y - self.location[1]
            distance_x = x - self.location[0]
            distance_y2 =  self.location[1] - y
            distance_x2 =  self.location[0] - x

            if x > self.location[0] and not self.location[0]>=x:
                ratio = distance_x/distance_y
                speed_x = ratio * speed
                self.speed_x=speed_x
                prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print
            else: self.speed_x=0

            if y > self.location[1] and not self.location[1]>=y:
                ratio = distance_y/distance_x
                speed_y = ratio * speed
                self.speed_y=speed_y
            else: self.speed_y=0

            if x < self.location[0] and not self.location[0]<=x:
                print('X')
                ratio = distance_x/distance_y
                speed_x = ratio * speed
                self.speed_x=speed_x*-1
                prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print
            else: self.speed_x=0;

            if y < self.location[1] and not self.location[1]<=y:
                ratio = distance_y/distance_x
                speed_y = ratio * speed
                self.speed_y=speed_y *-1
            else: self.speed_y=0

class rectangle(shape):
    size=[0,0]

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,[self.location,self.size])
        self.update_pos()
#=============VARIABLES=========================================================
block=rectangle()
block.color=RED
block.location=[50,50]
block.size=[50,50]
#===============================================================================
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) #set screen size and create screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Dud's game") #name of screen
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # EVENTS ===================================================================
    prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print. <------ seems to get set to 0 here 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    # LOGIC ====================================================================
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    block.move(200,200,3)
    # DRAW =====================================================================
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    block.draw()
    text('hello',[10,10])

    pygame.display.flip()
    # END ======================================================================
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
print(prints)
```

block.speed_x gets set to 0, as far as i can tell, at the start of the loop. the only time i have told it to be = 0 was at `block=rectangle()` where the class sets the speed to 0 by default, and in move, where if the rectangle has reached the palce it is supposed to be at it stops: `else: self.speed_x=0;`.

the results of the temp prints:

```
[0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 0]
```

Comment: Inside your `move` method you have `self.speed_x=0`.

Comment: You set it to 0 here as well: `else: self.speed_x=0`

Comment: yes, forgot about that. that's supposed to be there and isn't causing the problem.

Comment: why is this getting down votes? i'm not sure what else to add. its a simple question.

Comment: This is essentially "please debug my code for me" question. Most likely it's too narrow to be useful outside this concrete case, so contribute little to overall SO content. Hence the downvotes. Also, it might be a good idea to reduce the code in question as much as possible.

Comment: @J0HN where do i put it then? i have worked on this for atleast 2 hours and cant find the problem. is there another site i can put it?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd say that it could be these lines: `ratio = distance_x/distance_y`, `speed_x = ratio * speed`. If both distance are `int`s, then ratio could end up being zero.

Comment: @SiHa just added a print and ratio comes out as 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be in here:

block.move(200,200,3) will set x on the function as 200. Then you evaluate first condition and it calculates the speed, since x is 200 and is > self.location[0] which is valued to 50.

This is correct, but a few lines below you check again for the second if condition and then x will not meet that condition (since it's opposite) and therefore the speed will be reset to zero.

```
    if x > self.location[0] and not self.location[0]>=x:
        ratio = distance_x/distance_y
        speed_x = ratio * speed
        self.speed_x=speed_x
        prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print
    else: self.speed_x=0

    if y > self.location[1] and not self.location[1]>=y:
        ratio = distance_y/distance_x
        speed_y = ratio * speed
        self.speed_y=speed_y
    else: self.speed_y=0

    if x < self.location[0] and not self.location[0]<=x:
        print('X')
        ratio = distance_x/distance_y
        speed_x = ratio * speed
        self.speed_x=speed_x*-1
        prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print
    else: self.speed_x=0;

    if y < self.location[1] and not self.location[1]<=y:
        ratio = distance_y/distance_x
        speed_y = ratio * speed
        self.speed_y=speed_y *-1
    else: self.speed_y=0
```

I don't get the reason for a double check on every single one of the if statements (anyway I'm not touching those), but I think you should try with an if-elif-else statement, try the following:

```
if x > self.location[0] and not self.location[0]>=x:
    ratio = distance_x/distance_y
    speed_x = ratio * speed
    self.speed_x=speed_x
    prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print

elif x < self.location[0] and not self.location[0]<=x:
    print('X')
    ratio = distance_x/distance_y
    speed_x = ratio * speed
    self.speed_x=speed_x*-1
    prints.append(block.speed_x) #temp print

else: self.speed_x=0


if y > self.location[1] and not self.location[1]>=y:
    ratio = distance_y/distance_x
    speed_y = ratio * speed
    self.speed_y=speed_y

elif y < self.location[1] and not self.location[1]<=y:
    ratio = distance_y/distance_x
    speed_y = ratio * speed
    self.speed_y=speed_y *-1

else: self.speed_y=0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i don't think this makes any difference. the problem is block.speed_x (or self.speed_x) is being set to 0 somewhere.

Comment: My propose was based on the fact that there exists two conditions  for x and another two for y. The program will only hit the code on one of those two conditions, and therefore one of the conditions will ALWAYS reset self.speed to zero. Hope it is solved soon!

Comment: this fixes the problem but raises another, only one of the if statements will return true when 2 of them need to (a x and a y)

Comment: I just performed a few corrections, my answer was not right. I think now it is.

Comment: You are right, just noticed that while I was performing my last edition, so the answer now should be working good.

Comment: `x > self.location[0] and not self.location[0]>=x` is nonsense anyway. If `x > self.location[0]` is True then `self.location[0]>=x` wil _always_ be False.

Comment: yeah i had different code before that required that to be there, but forgot to remove it.